# Can somebody please explain about Openerp 7's installation in ubuntu inorder to have several different versions on the same machine

Tags: odoo, ubuntu-14.04, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have a few doubts on setting up several copies of openerp 7 on ubuntu 14.04 .

E.g.
If I have extracted all of these versions into my /opt/openerp/,

```
/opt/openerp/server [old unpatched version]
/opt/openerp/server_231025 [Old unpatched version of openerp 7]
/opt/openerp/server_231303 [latest patched openerp 7 version]
/opt/openerp/odoo_8 [Odoo version]
```

Now how do I proceed from here.
1. Do I have to copy each of their openerp-server.conf files and put it in /etc/ and rename  each one to make it different from one another.

2. And if I just want to autostart and autostop the first two and not the other two, then how do i do it.
3. Why do we put the openerp-server.conf in /etc/ eventhough it is already there under /opt/openerp/server/install/openerp-server.conf.
4. Is it compulsory to put the openerp-server.init from /server/install/ or its modified version into the /etc/init.d/ folder eventhough we do not want the openerp-server service to autostart and autostop. Is that what the init.d folder does, help autostart and autostop application services. Or is this step necessary to do a sudo service openerp-server start, stop, restart.
5. And what server does openerp use, gunicorn or a custom webdav based server.
6. Where exactly do we mention in the config file, the created role the openerp server has to use.

A detailed explanation would be really helpful and greatly appreciated.
Thanks a ton in advance. 
Please also take a look at my other questions and any answers is even more greatly appreciated with more kudos points.

Regards,
Vyas Senthil

Comment: I honestly believe your question is too broad. Answering would be like writeing a tutorial on setting up Odoo. I suggest a more focused question.

Comment: The long question was so as to let me set up several copies of openerp 7 on ubuntu 14.04 . If you could even answer a few of the above, I will be really grateful. Btw your blog has some really good stuff on openerp. Also please do take a look at my other question on client side validation using jquery in openerp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it by not using the packages but rather just tar.gz the files and put them in the directory we want.  The directory also includes the configuration file.  e.g /opt/rel_1, /opt/rel_2.

We then have one start script in /etc/init.d per instance and if required, one virtual environment per instance.  You need to set up the start scripts yourself this way but they are pretty simple.  As long as you use consistent path names inside the install directories it is pretty much a copy/paste exercise.

Auto-starting or not is up to you via the standard start tools on ubuntu (update-rc.d)

Assuming a recent Openerp (6.1 or greater), OpenERP/Odoo has werkzeug baked in but for prod you really want to use a wsgi server such as Nginx/Gunicorn or Apache/mod_wsgi.  I find nginx/gunicorn pretty simple but I don't really have any apache experience so can't comment.  In Odoo 8 they seem to have included in a multi-process option and gevent but I have yet to see any documentation on this.

Where you put the config file is up to you, just refer to it in the --config switch when you start openerp and it will work.

Comment: Kia Ora mate. Thanks a ton for helping me out. I would have upvoted if  I had the reputation. Can you also see if you could wing my other questions especially the one regarding client side validation using jquery in openerp. And can I hardcode the --config options in the openerp-server config file. Cheers.